# Can't find archive for package libx264-123

Tags: 12.10

I received a message saying  "There seems to be a programming error in aptdaemon, the software that allows you to install/remove software and to perform other package management related tasks." I then tried these commands

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a

sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

But at the end it returned an error saying `the package libx264-123 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it`.

Comment: I'd start with `sudo apt-get update`, and if that works, `sudo apt-get -f install`. Finally, if those run without crashing, I'd finish with `sudo apt-get upgragrade`.

Comment: Quantal has reached end-of-life. You need to upgrade to Trusty (14.04) (by going through Saucy (13.10)). See the guide [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SaucyUpgrades#Upgrade_from_13.04_or_12.10_to_13.10). You can also choose to do a fresh install of Trusty instead.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Ubuntu. I suggest you do a fresh install without formatting your root partition. Your data in /home will be preserved and a fresh install is faster and more reliable then an upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable the "universe" repository, that is the repo that contains the libx264-123 package.

You can do this by using the software center.

1. open Ubuntu Software Center
2. click on "Edit"
3. select "Software Sources" from the drop-down menu
4. make sure "Community-maintained free and open-source software
   (universe)" has a check or is selected
5. enter your password to accept the changes
6. Then,

run the following commands

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get purge x264 libx264-123 ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

**Before accepting** the changes, **take note** of what will be uninstalled. You will need to re-install any packages removed with that command!

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade    
sudo apt-get install x264 lib264-123 ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

Any other packages that were uninstalled earlier should be included in the final command to be reinstalled.

As a suggestion, you might want to install the synaptic package manager as it is a powerful and resourceful tool that is capable of configuring your sources as well as fixing and resolving dependency issues or broken packages.

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

and use

```
sudo synaptic
```

or

```
gksudo synaptic
```

to start it up.